# "TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" using reduce()

Tags: python, lambda

I want to return sum of square of numbers passed in list.

```
from functools import reduce

def square_sum(numbers):
    return reduce(lambda x: x ** 2, numbers)

print(square_sum([1, 2, 2]))
```

However i am getting the error: `TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.
I couldn't understand reason behind it.

Comment: Did you noticed `reduce` needs two arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you might define `sum` if it didn't exist:

```py
from functools import reduce

def sum(it):
    return reduce(lambda acc, val: acc + val, it)
```

Or:

```py
from functools import reduce
import operator

def sum(it):
    return reduce(operator.add, it)
```

`functools.reduce` reduces the values produced by an iterator to a single value by repeatedly combining consecutive values using the function you provide. So the function needs to be able to combine two values and therefore must take two arguments.

So you could define `sum_of_squares` using `reduce`, like this, although there are a lot of corner cases to cope with:

```py
from functools import reduce

def sum_of_squares(it):
    it = iter(it)
    try:
        first = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return 0
    return reduce(lambda acc, val: acc + val * val,
                  it,
                  first * first)
```

Personally, I think the following is clearer:

```py
def sum_of_squares(it):
    return sum(map(lambda x: x ** 2, it))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `function` parameter to [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) should take two arguments: an old one and a new one. To sum, you'd just need to add them together:

```
lambda r, x: x**2 + r
```

However, that doesn't actually do what you want because the first element never gets squared (so it doesn't get the right answer if the first element is >1). You might be thinking `reduce()` is like `sum(map())`:

```
def square_sum(numbers):
    return sum(map(lambda x: x**2, numbers))
```

But it's more readable to replace the `map` with a generator expression:

```
def square_sum(numbers):
    return sum(x**2 for x in numbers)

print(square_sum([1, 2, 2]))  # -> 9
```